# Do Google Play leaderboards authenticate data being sent?

Tags: android, authentication, google-play, leaderboard

I want to integrate a leaderboard into my Android game. However I am undecided about using my own server or using Google's leaderboards. The one thing that will tilt my preference is whether or not the Google system authenticates scores being sent. I don't want someone to get the leaderboard ID (or some other data) and send fake scores to the board. If I make my own system (e.g. in PHP) I can at least set up a method to authenticate scores being sent to the server. E.g. by using a hashing system.

So is there any information about how Google authenticates data being send by apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no server-side score validation.

Your game can attach some extra metadata with each submission, but you (or a script) need to poll the leaderboard and manually remove bogus entries.  See [Google Play Game Services Management Tools](http://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools/tree/master/tools/hide-o-matic).

(I've used the extra metadata in a word game attaching an anti-tamper hash as well other information about what the user actually did.  I haven't caught any bogus hash-mismatched submissions, but it is a handy way to see what the top-scoring players are actually doing.)

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful. Thus far I have decided not to store scores in human readable form in the shared prefs location. The scores will be stored in hashed format and will be decrypted by the application before they are sent to the leaderboard. Many thanks.